# Import/Export HTML5 localStorage data

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm working on a simple TODO list app based on localStorage HTML5 feature:

http://hamen.github.com/webnotes/

I'm wondering if it's possible to import/export data in some way. How could I provide an "Export note/Import note" feature to make users being able to save their note on their HD and import them in another browser profile?

Thanks

Comment: I'm interested in this too. The best I've thought of so far (without server-side code) isn't very nice: dump the data a JSON or something into a textarea or div, and let the user copy/paste it.  If you can program the server, of course, you can have your site just bundle up the data, post it to the server, and have the server respond with a downloadable attachment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you can use the ["HTML File API"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_files_from_web_applications) to load from file and a "Data URI" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) to save.