# convert a webpage to pdf form and download it

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf

I have submitted a form resulting in a webpage, I need to download that webpage in any format.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you just want to trigger "Save as" operation in browser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger a Browser's Save-As Dialog via Javascript using only On-page data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799669/trigger-a-browsers-save-as-dialog-via-javascript-using-only-on-page-data)

Comment: i can't understand that

Answer (score 0):

Ya its very easy to do with javascript. Hope this code is useful to you.

Yes, Use jspdf To create a pdf file.

```
<div id="content">
     <h3>Hello, this is a H3 tag</h3>

    <p>a pararaph</p>
</div>
<div id="editor"></div>
<button id="cmd">Generate PDF</button>

<script>
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    var specialElementHandlers = {
        '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    $('#cmd').click(function () {
        doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
            'width': 170,
                'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        });
        doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
    });

    // This code is collected but useful, click below to jsfiddle link.
</script>
```

Comment: In the question, OP state that webpage can be downloaded in "any format"

Comment: on clicking the button there is no reaction what should I do now