# Can you access a Browser's Save As Functionality in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, download, save

I'm creating a webpage, which should be easily downloadable by users.

Ideally, I'd like there to be a button at the bottom of the page which activates the browser's `save as` function. I'd like to do it this way because not everybody knows how to save a web page.

Is it possible to activate the browser's `save as` functionality via a button press in Javascript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger a Browser's Save-As Dialog via Javascript using only On-page data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799669/trigger-a-browsers-save-as-dialog-via-javascript-using-only-on-page-data)

Comment: @technophyle No, it's 11 years old, and it says "I don't ***think***" this is possible. I'd like an up-to-date answer with certainty! Thank you for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to trigger browser's Save As dialog upon click of a button.

However, it *is* possible to trigger download of the current page using the `download` attribute of an `a` tag.

Sample code:

```js
function triggerDownload(url, fileName) {
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = url;
  link.download = fileName;
  link.click();
}

// call the above method to trigger download
triggerDownload('https://<current-page-url>', 'page.html');
```

The caveat of the above code is that it only downloads HTML and *not* the accompanying CSS/JS. So, in order to mitigate that, it's probably better to trigger `window.print()` to allow users to download the whole page as a PDF:

```
function triggerDownload() {
  window.print();
}
```

There are also libraries you can use to do the PDF conversion (such as `jsPDF`) without using the print dialog.

Comment: Does that download the html only?

Comment: any file. for example, `triggerDownload('https://my-domain.com/file.pdf', 'file.pdf');` works.

Comment: Sorry, specifically, will a single `triggerDownload('my_url', 'my_file')` capture and save all the supporting CSS and Javascript, or not?

Comment: um.. no, I don't think it downloads the supporting CSS/JS.

Comment: another option you have is to call `window.print()` to download the current page as a PDF.