# Does HTML 5 allow to invoke save file dialog with file created in JavaScript?

Tags: html

Does HTML 5 allow to invoke save file dialog with file created in JavaScript?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking about. Please provide more info about your scenario.

Comment: How do you create a file with Javascript?

Comment: I believe @Alexey is asking how to create content in Javascript that the user can save as a normal file. Specifically without requiring the content to traverse through a server. Or at least, that's the question I would like an answer for :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested data-uri approach. Currently it works only in Firefox.

Seems that for now it is better to stay with flash: https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify

Comment: Data URIs work in IE8, WebKit and Opera too, how were you testing it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you don't really need HTML5 for it, what you can use is a [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).  There are several limitations, like IE8 only allows files up to 32Kb, and you'll need to get the user to click on a link.  [See my answer to a similar question for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286423/is-it-possible-to-use-any-html5-fanciness-to-export-local-storage-to-excel/3293101#3293101).

In the future you may be able to use the [File Writer API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/), but I'm not aware of any browser support for that yet.