# Content-disposition or others in http-equiv?

Tags: html, http, http-headers, meta-tags

Are the list of headers supported by the `http-equiv` meta tags a limited subset, or does it accept literally anything that you could have as an http header?

Specifically, could I use `content-disposition`?

Answer (score 4):

Almost all `meta` tags are ignored by browsers, search engines, and other software.

Even though the HTML 4.01 spec says that “HTTP servers use [the `http-equiv`] attribute to gather information for HTTP response message headers”, this does not happen. (It happened for a few such attributes very long ago in some special servers.) Instead, `meta` tags with `http-equiv` attribute are recognized by *browsers*, but only in very few cases. The most important case is that `http-equiv="Content-Type"` may be used to decide on character encoding, if it has been specified in actual HTTP headers.

In HTML5 drafts, `meta` tags with `http-equiv` attribute are called “[pragma directives](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-meta-element.html#pragma-directives)”, and an explicit list of allowed values is specified. All the rest are thus non-conforming (and, in practice, mostly write-only tags, ignored by browsers).

You cannot affect anything using `content-disposition` there. To affect the way a browser deals with, say, a CSV file that you link to in your HTML document, there is probably nothing you can do *in HTML*. You would have to make the server send actual HTTP headers, typically so that your link refers to a server-side script that fetches the CSV file and sends it along with suitable HTTP headers.

Comment: Hi there... Thanks for the nice explanation! So actually, what I'm trying to do is something slightly different, *the other way around*, in a way.  Basically, I have an HTML page rendered already in the browser, of course containing some Javascript.  And then I want to do some magic which I haven't quite worked out yet to spark a "save file as..." dialog, from the already loaded javascript.  The file I want to get downloaded is itself HTML, and I'd want it to get saved with an HTML extension....

Comment: But I think the best path I've come up with to explore is `location = 'data:`(some-mime-type)`;`(some-http-header-thingies)`,<!doctype html><meta charset=utf-8><title>t</title><p>my html page</p>`.  I think the ones to explore are `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition`, and then I think there could be hope in spoofing the MIMEtype to something which the browser knows it can't handle.  Like if I make a mimetype of exe chromium can't really do anything with that except for offer the user to dump it into their FS.  But then I wonder if I'll be restricted to using a `.exe` filename, y'know?

Comment: Any more tips on achieving what I described?

Comment: I don’t quite get what you are trying to achieve, but I think a) it would belong under a different heading, b) it’s probably not possible, for security reasons, c) it’s difficult to imagine when it might be *needed*. Saving an HTML file from a browser is such a simple operation that anyone who could possibly benefit from it can be expected to know how to do it.

Comment: @haxxerz Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3286423/8655), you should also read up on the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) (though it isn't universally supported yet).