# Storing HTML5 localstorage data to some other file

Tags: html, local-storage

Is it possible to store HTML5 local storage data to some other .txt or .doc or excel file?

Because, i want to backup the local storage data to some other file.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845603/import-export-html5-localstorage-data for an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is asking whether it is possible to tell the browser to translate local storage to a .txt or .doc file, the answer is no. Local storage is implemented in the browser and stays in the browser (as [defined by W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#dom-localstorage)).

If you want to have some mechanism that converts local storage data to a file system file, you probably want to use the [File API](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/pub/FileSystem/#using-localfilesystem) instead.

Comment: Exactly, I want to store it in a file i.e .xml or .doc or .txt format.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a client side file using HTML5. [This link](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side) shows how to do that. Be careful though, not all browsers support this feature.